# Adding an Exchange account in macOS doesn't show server options

Tags: macos, exchange

I'm trying to add an Exchange account using the Internet Accounts preference pane on macOS Monterey, but the option to manually set the Exchange server is not there anymore (I have also tried on Ventura and downgraded to Monterey to sort this out).

Does anyone know if there is a way to set the Exchange server using command line, or how to get the option to manually configure the Exchange server back?

This is not a Microsoft 365 account.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Have you typed your email address and pressed Sign In? Mail tries to set up the account automatically for you, but if that fails (and in my experience, for Exchange accounts, that's usually the case) it will request that you provide a mail server.

Comment: When it fails it does present another page where it ask for name, mail, username and password, but never for the server settings, I do remember in previous OS it asked for hostname and that the option I was looking for

Comment: No, it's always asked for the internal and external URL's.  On macOS, Exchange support is EWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange support on macOS is via EWS.

[image]
Click Sign-In.  If there is a server accessible that responds to auto-discover, it will populate.  Otherwise...

[image]
Click "Configure Manually".  You will be taken to a dialog asking you for the password of the account.
[image]

Click "Sign-In" again.

[image]

And you are now prompted for the Internal and External URL's.

Comment: In this way it doesn't work and that why I raised this question.
It didn't present the external URL internal URL prompt.
But I found after you comment that if you remove the after @ then it present the questions of server external internal ....
amazing complicate